# Dynamically creating accessors in Ruby module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a Config module in Ruby that I want to be able to add arbitrary variables to. I have created it using method_missing and instance_variable_set as follows:

```
module Conf
  #add arbitrary methods to config array
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    args = args.pop if args.length==1
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)     
  end
end
```

However, I'm having trouble with dynamically creating accessors. When I try to use attr_accessor as follows:

```
module Conf
  #add arbitrary methods to config array
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    args = args.pop if args.length==1
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)     
    module_eval("attr_accessor :#{m}")
  end
end
```

I get the following:

Conf::s3_key('1234ABC')   #Conf::s3_key=nil

And if I try to create the accessors separately:

```
module Conf
  #add arbitrary methods to config array
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    args = args.pop if args.length==1
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)
    module_eval("def self.#{m};@#{m};end")
    module_eval("def self.#{m}=(val);@#{m}=val;end")
  end
end
```

The following happens:

```
Conf::s3_key('1234ABC') # Conf::s3_key='1234ABC' - correct
```

but if I try to overwrite the value I get an error

```
Conf::s3_key('1234ABC') # ok
Conf::s3_key('4567DEF') #(eval):1:in `s3_key': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use OpenStruct?

Comment: Setting the class instance variable works fine, so it appears to me that your main problem is the dynamic creation of a read-write accessor for that class instance variable, given that its name is one of `missing_method`'s arguments. Is that correct?

Comment: @CodeGnome - I need other functionality besides just storing the hashes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `attr_accessor` is unusable for Module, even if normally described.

```
module Conf
  attr_accessor :s3_key
end
```

Second, the error of overwriting is because `method_missing` is executed only once

```
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    #:
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)
    module_eval("def self.#{m};@#{m};end") # <- method defined
```

the method is defined in first call.
And the number of arguments is 0

```
Conf::s3_key('1234ABC') # call method_missing
Conf::s3_key('4567DEF') # call self.s3_key()
```

For example, how about like this:

```
module Conf
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    args = args.pop if args.length==1
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)
    module_eval(<<EOS)
def self.#{m}(*args)
  if (args.empty?)
    @#{m}
  else
    @#{m} = (args.length==1) ? args.pop : args
  end
end
EOS
  end
end

Conf::s3_key('foo')
Conf::s3_key('bar')
p Conf::s3_key                   # "bar"
```

Or

```
module Conf
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    if (m.to_s =~ /^(.+)=$/)
      args = args.pop if args.length==1
      instance_variable_set("@#{$1}", args)
    else
      instance_variable_get("@#{m}")
    end
  end
end

Conf::s3_key = 'foo'
Conf::s3_key = 'bar'
p Conf::s3_key                   # "bar"
```

Comment: That worked, thank you.  

What's the reason that calling module_eval twice in method_missing didn't work, as it looked to me like it should be functionally similar to this solution (obviously, it's not because yours works and mine doesn't!)

Comment: yohshiy, actually `attr_accessor` can be used for modules.  (See my answer.)  Yesterday I would have agreed with you, but after thinking about it, and working on it, it's actually quite straightforward.

Comment: @lain In `method_missing`, s3_key() method is defined. the number of arguments of the method is **0**. `Conf::s3key('4567DEF')` <- the number of arguments is **1**. In my sample, `s3_key(*args)` is defined.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right. I didn't think of using `eval` on `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change one line of your code.

**Code**

```
module Conf
  def self.method_missing(m, *args)
    args = args.pop if args.length==1
    instance_variable_set("@#{m}", args)     
    Module.instance_eval("attr_accessor :#{m}")
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
Conf.s3_key('1234ABC')
Conf.s3_key             #=> "1234ABC"
Conf.s3_key = '4567DEF'
Conf.s3_key             #=> "4567DEF"
```

(Or `Conf::s3_key('1234ABC')`, etc.)

**Explanation**

Accessors are defined for classes and apply to class instances.  In this case the class instance is the module `Conf`, so `attr_accessor` must be defined for the class of which `Conf` is an instance:

```
Conf.class #=> Module
```

Note that

```
Module.is_a? Class       #=> true
Conf.instance_of? Module #=> true
```

We do this by invoking [BasicObject#instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) on `Module`.  We need to use `instance_eval` so that the variable `m` will be in scope when it is invoked.

One last observation.  Suppose the module `Conf` were enclosed by another module `M`.  Then the code still works:

```
   M::Conf.s3_key('1234ABC')
   M::Conf.s3_key             #=> "1234ABC"
   M::Conf.s3_key = '4567DEF'
   M::Conf.s3_key             #=> "4567DEF"
```

That's because *all* modules, including nested ones, are instances of the class `Module`.

Comment: That approach works well when I try it as published, but in my actual use-case, I get `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`

Rather than calling Conf.s3_key directly, I am doing:

`config do 
   s3_key "1234ABC"
   s3_key "4567DEF"
 end`

This then calls a function in my Base class:

`def self.config (&block)
    Conf.module_eval(&block)
  end`

Which invokes Conf as above

Comment: Iain, try calling `config` like this: `BaseClass.config { s3_key "1234ABC"; s3_key = "456DEF" }`.  I think your problem is that `s3_key "456DEF"` invokes the read method for `s3_key` that `method_missing` created when `s3_key "1234ABC"` was executed.  That method takes zero arguments, but you passed one.

Comment: Iain, note that you could use `instance_eval` rather than `module_eval` (aka `class_eval`) in your class method `config` (just as I could have used `module_eval` instead of `instance_eval` in `method_missing`.)  That's because `module_eval` evaluates the string in the context of `Conf`, whereas `instance_eval` evaluates the string in the context of the instance `Conf` of the class `Module`.  Same thing!