# How to initialize ruby class variable in module

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have code like this:

```
class TestClass
  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :number

    def initialize
      @number = 47
    end
  end

  include ClassMethods
  extend ClassMethods
end
```

`TestClass.new.number` returns `47`, which is expected, but `TestClass.number` returns `nil`.

How can I initialize `number` variable for both `TestClass` class and `TestClass` instances?
So far, I've done it like this:

```
class TestClass
  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :number

    def initialize
      @number = 47
    end
  end

  include ClassMethods
  extend ClassMethods
  @number = 47
end
```

I do not like this approach because `number` is initialized in two places.

Comment: The first number is for a given instance of `TestClass`; the second is a class instance variable.  They can coexist, as they are as different as `@night` and `@day`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I understand that. My question is why "extend ClassMethods" doesn't initialize class instance variable. And how can I initialize both instance variable and class instance variable without having duplicate code?

Comment: xx, I hadn't forgotten. It just took me awhile to find time to provide an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had this:

```
class TestClass
  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :number    
    def initialize
      @number = 47
    end
  end
  include ClassMethods
  extend  ClassMethods
end
```

Let's get some information about this class:

```
TestClass.instance_variables #=> []
```

No surprise there.

```
tc = TestClass.new      #=> #<TestClass:0x00000101098a10 @number=47>
p tc.instance_variables #=> [:@number]
tc.number               #=> 47
tc.number = 11
```

All as expected. The instance variable `@number` was created by `initialize` and we can inspect and change its value with the accessor.

`extend` made `TestClass#initialize` a class method, but it has not been invoked. Let's invoke it to initialize the class instance variable `@number`:

```
TestClass.initialize
  #=> NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for TestClass:Class
```

Ah, yes, `initialize`is a private method.

```
TestClass.methods.include?(:initialize)         #=> false
TestClass.private_methods.include?(:initialize) #=> true
```

We cannot invoke private class methods in the usual way. `send`, however, works with private as well as public methods:

```
TestClass.send :initialize                      #=> 47
TestClass.instance_variables                    #=> [:@number]
TestClass.instance_variable_get(:@number)       #=> 47
```

So now the class instance variable has been created set equal to `47`. Has it changed the value of the instance variable `@number`?

```
tc.number                                       #=> 11
```

It's not changed.  Now let's change the value of the class instance variable and then see if the value of instance variable is affected:

```
TestClass.instance_variable_set(:@number, -5)   #=> -5
tc.number                                       #=> 11
```

If you'd like to add an accessor for the class instance variable `@number`, add this line to the class or module:

```
Module.instance_eval("attr_accessor :number")
```

(For an explanation, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946576/dynamically-creating-accessors-in-ruby-module/24967591#24967591).)

Then test:

```
TestClass.number       #=> -5
TestClass.number = 107
TestClass.number       #=> 107
```

Comment: Thanks, I was on the right track, except I tried calling initialize without using send.
Whoever downvoted - can you explain?